# Remove duplicate elements of string1 from string2 in Tcl

Tags: scripting, tcl

I want to remove duplicate elements of string1 from string 2 and then output new string. My code works only if duplicate elements are in sequential order. 
I want to work it any order of elements. Please advise.

Current Code:

```
set str1  "a 1 b 2 c 3 X Y Z"
set str2  "a 1 b 2 c 3 P Q R"
set results {}


set results [lmap a_elem $str1 b_elem $str2 {
    if {$a_elem != $b_elem} {string cat $b_elem} else continue      
}]   

puts $results
```

Output of the following code :
`P Q R`

However, if

```
set str1 "a 1 b 2 c 3 X Y Z"
set str2 "P a 2 1 R c Q 3 b"
```

then Output will be  : `P a 2 1 R c Q 3 b`

Basically same as str2 without the duplicate elimnation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two lists and returning the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524552/comparing-two-lists-and-returning-the-difference) Essentially the same thing. You can take the answers there a tweak to return only one side of the difference as required.

Comment: @Jerry Yes that does answer my question, need some tweaking like you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance is not important, you can use the more straight forward:

```
set results [lmap elem $str2 {
    if {$elem ni $str1} {string cat $elem} else continue
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to output those elements of the *list* in `str2` that are nowhere in `str1`, you should first build a dictionary of the elements of `str1` so that you can use efficient lookup (dicts are internally hash tables). You are *strongly* recommended to use a procedure for this as it makes the implementation rather more efficient.

```
proc removeItems {str1 str2} {
    foreach item $str1 {
        dict set items $item ""; # Value unimportant
    }
    lmap item $str2 {
        if {[dict exists $items $item]} continue
        string cat $item
    }
}

puts [removeItems "a 1 b 2 c 3 X Y Z"  "P a 2 1 R c Q 3 b"]
# P R Q
```

The code naturally assumes that the order of `str2` is important.

Comment: For Large datasets and making it more efficient your solution works qith quicker runtime. Thanks,